# TYPO3 : personalize menus using PHP

Tags: php, typo3

My chief project got an old project on `TYPO3` and i have to do a modification on this but i don't know this `CMS` (but as a web developer i know PHP). I have to not display a submenu if customer came by a specific url (as www.website/specific/).

As I never used `TYPO3` I tried something like this :

- I create `$_session`'s var if url `preg_match` with specific url in `typo3_src-4.5.29/index.php`
- I create `custom_file.php` in t3lib which i call using `USER_INT` http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/UserAndUserInt/Index.html,
  this file send a submenu if there is no `$_session`'s var
- I create `js_custom_file.php` which i call using option2 here http://huuah.com/including-javascript-or-css-in-your-typo3-template/, this file using for redirect on the specific page
- In db i change in the two lines about menu, part of submenu by this :

`includeLibs.session = t3lib/custom_session_owner.php
page = PAGE
page.10 = USER_INT
page.10 {
    userFunc = getOwner
}
page.includeJS {
    custom_owner = t3lib/js_custom_owner.php
    custom_owner.type = application/x-javascript
}`

I know this is very ugly but i don't know how to do by another way. More of that, i think next time i will be in charge of this website it will be to rebuild on another CMS.

So if someone had a dirty quick trick i will be thankful :)

Comment: You mean you basically would like to display a different menu on a specific page?

Comment: Exactly i want to display a different menu on entire website if user came with a specific URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by adding a condition to the menu building part of your TypoScript configuration. http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Index.html

A basic example could look like this:

```
[globalString = IENV:HTTP_REFERER = http://www.google.com/*]
  # this section is only evalutated if the referer is set to www.google.com
lib.menu.special.value = 1234
[GLOBAL]
```

You may also use a regular expression.
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#condition-globalstring

Please keep in mind that such conditions can only be used in the GLOBAL scope of the TS configuration, that means it can not be inside `{}`.

Also keep in mind the the referrer comes the user, that means it can be faced any way the user wants it to look. There is no way you can deterministicly find out where a user comes from.

Of course you can use such a condition anywhere in your TS configuration, therefore also as a wrapper to the `USER_INT` content object.